# PHP: translate virtual path to physical path

Tags: php

Is it possible to translate a server relative virtual path to physical path in PHP?

e.g. if I have a url:

```
/home/index.php
```

then find the physical path of index.php somehow from some other script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

```
$path = 'mydir/index.php';
echo realpath($path);
```

Answer (score 5):

Prepend `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to the script path.